# Not able to convert internal svgs in an svg to canvas with canvg

Tags: svg, canvg

I have an SVG which embeds other SVG's with  . When I use canvg as described [here](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) , only the components on the original SVG are converted to canvas and the linked ones are omitted. Any solution?

Comment: how are you linking them? Try converting things to data URIs so they are part of the same document.

Comment: They are currently linked as such 
<svg>
     <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="canvas">
         <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/bubble.svg#self" transform="translate(300,0)"/>
    </g>
</svg>

Comment: As I said you need to convert the "/svg/bubble.svg#self" into a data URI so that it is not external any more.